# how manage connection and channels of RabbitMq in android

Tags: java, android, rabbitmq

i'm developing an android notification service with RabbitMq. it works fine but there is a problem. my notification service open a connection every 30 sec and after receiving messages it will close the channel and connection. and exactly my problem is here!if there is two user that are using my application at maximum there should be two connection and two channel ! but i tested my application and there was about 45 connection & channel open. i dont know whats wrong with my codes! here is my codes:

```
     //------- start service every 30 sec on--------------------


        Intent ishintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotificationService.class);
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, ishintent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.cancel(pintent);
        alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 30000, 30000, pintent);



        //---------------------- END SERVICE----------------------------
```

---

```
    public class NotificationService extends Service
{

    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    Connection connection;
    Channel channel;
    SharedPreferences sp1;
    String unm;
    String HostName = "my IP";
    String UserName = "user";
    String Password = "pass";

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {


    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {

        sp1=getSharedPreferences("Login", 0);
        unm=sp1.getString("Usr", null);
        String qName=unm;
        String routeKey=unm;
        if( isOnline()) {

            new AsyncSubscribe().execute(qName, routeKey);


                      }

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }


 // close connection when service finish 
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (connection.isOpen()) {

            try {
                channel.close();
                connection.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                Log.e("MYAPP", "exception", e);

            } catch (TimeoutException e) {

                Log.e("MYAPP", "exception", e);
            }


        }

    }



    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

// set connection and channels
    public void SubscribeSet() {


        try {
            factory.setHost(HostName);
            factory.setUsername(UserName);
            factory.setPassword(Password);
            connection = factory.newConnection();
            channel = connection.createChannel();
        }
        catch ( Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("MYAPP", "exception", e);
        }

    }


    private class AsyncSubscribe extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {
        Consumer consumer;
        boolean flag=true;
               @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String ... params) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(params);

                     // do something

        }

             @Override
                 protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

                 SubscribeSet();

                  try {

                    channel.exchangeDeclare("logs", "fanout", true);
                    channel.exchangeDeclare("direct_logs", "direct", true);
                    channel.queueDeclare(params[0], true, false, false, null);
                    channel.queueBind(params[0], "logs", "");
                    channel.queueBind(params[0], "direct_logs", params[1]);

                    consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
                        @Override
                        public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body)
                        throws IOException {
                            properties.builder().deliveryMode(2);
                            publishProgress(new String(body, "UTF-8"));

                        }
                    };
                      // listen to channel ..
                    channel.basicConsume(params[0], true, consumer);


                      try {

                          // close connection after 10 sec listening to port
                          Thread.sleep(10000);
                          channel.close();
                          connection.close();
                          stopSelf();


                      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                         Log.e("MYAPP", "exception", e);

                      }



            }
            catch ( Exception e) {

                  Log.e("MYAPP", "exception", e);

            }

            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hey hi did you get any solution for this.. i am also facing same issue?

Comment: @GangaNaidu yes. http://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html